# Cannot connect to remote computer when using PuTTY ssh

Tags: ssh, putty

I have a remote server with Ubuntu 12.04 installed.
I want to use PuTTY to establish connection, but I get a fatal error.
The information is show as below:

```
Couldn't agree a host key algorithm (available ecdsa-sha2-nistp256)
```

I have searched the solution by Google but failed. I just want to know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You should set up your ssh server to offer different host keys that are supported by putty or make putty accept this key type (update putty. It should [support them](http://ssh-comparison.quendi.de/impls/putty.html)).

On server side, you would need to generate the keys and set up in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` option `HostKey` pointing to them and make sure the key type is also available in option `HostKeyAlgorithms`.

Comment: Updating putty helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was getting exactly the same error from putty after upgrading an Ubuntu server from 14.04.1 to 16.04.1. The version of putty I was using was the latest recommended version 0.67, however I solved my issue by using the latest development snapshot version (snapshot 2016-08-30.bf00bcd at the time of writing this).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, putty wanted an RSA host key.

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key`

Then un-comment the line that refers to that file in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, and restart sshd.